# Flutter swap current Firebase Project with another

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have a current Flutter project which is linked to a Firebase project and is reading and writing from a Realtime Database. My issue is that I have used the wrong project and now want to switch my Flutter app to use a different Project's Realtime Database. Is it possible to switch the Firebase project my app is currently linked to and if so how do I go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [FlutterFire CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) is a great tool for quickly configuring Firebase resources for Flutter projects and it could be used to switch the Firebase project to which the configuration files in your Flutter project are pointed.

First you could want to set up the FlutterFire CLI by following the instructions on the Firebase site:

1. [Install the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#setup_update_cli).
2. Log into Firebase using the Google account under which you have the new Firebase project you want to switch to set up by running the following command: `firebase login`
3. Install the FlutterFire CLI by running the following command from any directory: `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`

Then, after getting the FlutterFire CLI set up, it would probably be a good idea to make sure your current Firebase configuration is backed up some how, either using version control or manually.

Finally, to switch your Flutter configuration to a different Firebase project, run `flutterfire configure` and follow the steps in the workflow, making sure to select the new Firebase project.